# Microsoft To-Do's Open Email in Outlook.exe

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When flagging an email in outlook you can set this up to sync between Microsoft To-Do's

To-Do's gives you the option to open the flagged message but this opens in outlook online where it would be preferred to open in outlook desktop app.

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Currently it is not possible. There is even a [thread](https://todo.uservoice.com/forums/597175-feature-suggestions/suggestions/37091575-open-email-with-outlook-desktop) at Uservoice requesting for the ability to open the emails via the Outlook on the desktop since March 2019. But Microsoft developers have not yet implemented it.

Comment: Ah, atleast im not the only one. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND**** You can drag the email to the task as an attachment. it will attach as .msg and when you select it, the original email will open using Outlook Desktop. Not ideal but an easy solution to get the desired outcome for now.